# PHP messages aren't being written to the log file - tutsplus.com tutorial

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931), there you will find a tutorial which guides you through the steps on how to create a simple web chat. I tried to follow all that was said, yet I noticed a problem when testing. It seems that the usermsg is not being posted to the log.html file.

here is the index.php, which in this case is named chat.php:

```
<?php
    function loginForm() {
        echo '
        <div id="loginform">
            <form action="chat.php" method="post">
                <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="enter">
            </form>
        </div>
        ';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['enter'])) {
        if($_POST['name'] != "") {
            $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        }else {
            echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
        }
    }   

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Chat Service</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" title="style" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
                loginForm();
            }else{
        ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="welcome">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["name"];  ?></div>
                <div class="logout"><a href="#" id="exit">Exit Chat</a></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="chatbox"><?php
                if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0) {
                    $handle = fopen("log.html", "r");
                    $contents = fread($handle, filesize("log.html"));
                    fclose($handle);

                    echo $contents;
                }
                ?></div>
            <form name="message" action="">
                <input type="text" name="usermsg" id="usermsg" size="63">
                <input type="submit" name="submitmsg" id="submitmsg" value="Send">  
            </form>
        </div>  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //jQuery Document
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#exit").click(function() {
                    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");
                    if(exit == true) {
                        window.location = 'chat.php?logout=true';
                    }
                });

            $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
                var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
                console.log(clientmsg);
                $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});
                $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
                return false;
            });

            function loadLog() {
                var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                $.ajax({
                    url:"log.html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                            $("#chatbox").html(html);

                            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight) {
                                $("#chatbox").animate({scrollTop: newscrollHeight}, 'normal');
                            }
                        }
                });
            }

            setInterval(loadLog, 2500);
            });         
        </script>           
        <?php       
            }   
            if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
                $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
                fwrite($fp, '<div class="msgln"><i>User '.$_SESSION['name'].' has left the chat session.</i><br></div>');
                fclose($fp);

                session_destroy();
                header("Location: chat.php");
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the post.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").")<b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>:".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
        fclose($fp);
    }

?>
```

I am using MAMP, and the files are located in the htdocs folder, so that's not the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me, and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking return values from fopen to see if your file ever got created/appended? Plus, you never call session_start() in your index.php, which probably means that your chat.php will just skip your file writing code entirely.

Comment: That's what was missing! I looked over this code various times and completely forgot about the session_start(). Turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `session_start()` in index.php.

<sup>([from Marc B in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973660/php-messages-arent-being-written-to-the-log-file-tutsplus-com-tutorial#comment44340302_27973660))</sup>